# Swap the second list parameter's first element with the the first list parameter's first element, then return this list using the function below

Tags: list, haskell

Implement the

```
replaceHead :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

function, that works as the title says.
For example:

```
replaceHead "okay" "mom" == "mkay"
```

or:

```
replaceHead [0,2,3] [1,20,30] == [1,2,3]
```

I tried using

```
replaceHead a b = [head b, a]
```

which doesn't compile. I don't have any more ideas as to how I can take b's first element, swap it with a's first element, and then return that list. Can you help?
Thanks for you answers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `a` is a list of items, whereas `head b` is an item. You can thus not use `[head b, a]` since then the first item is for example an `Int`, whereas `a` is an `[Int]`. In order to meet the sample output, we furthermore need to work with the *tail* of the first list, not the entire first list.

You can however prepend the `tail a` list by using the `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` data constructor:

```
replaceHead :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replaceHead a b = head b : tail a
```

It might be better to work with pattern matching here, and implement this as:

```
replaceHead :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replaceHead (_:as) (b:_) = b : as
```

In that case you probably should define a case when the first and/or second list is empty:

```
replaceHead :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replaceHead (_:as) (b:_) = b : as
replaceHead [] [] = …
replaceHead [] (b:bs) = …
replaceHead (a:as) [] = …
```

Comment: Do note that this does not have the required behaviour, now `replaceHead "okay" "mom" == "mokay"`.

Comment: @Noughtmare: arrrghhh yes, The title did not summarize it correctly. Thanks, updated now.

Comment: Your first solution was right. Sorry, if the title was a little bit misleading. Thank you for your help.